# Converting this event handler from C# to VB .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling

So I'm using this Spotify wrapper here:

[Wrapper](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET#spotifyapi-net)

and I'm attempting to convert the example provided to VB .NET from C#. I've converted every piece of code except for this one handler section.

Here is the C#:

```
eh.OnTrackChange += New SpotifyEventHandler.TrackChangeEventHandler(trackchange);
```

and here is my attempt of converting it to VB:

```
AddHandler eh.OnTrackChange, New SpotifyEventHandler.TrackChangeEventHandler(AddressOf trackchange)
```

No errors are thrown, however it simply doesn't work.

Here is `TrackChange`:

```
Private Sub trackchange(e As TrackChangeEventArgs)
    status.Text = "Now Playing: " + mh.GetCurrentTrack().GetTrackName() + " by " + mh.GetCurrentTrack().GetArtistName()
    speak(status.Text)
End Sub
```

The status text doesn't change and the speak method isn't called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the event is raised?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'm still learning, could you perhaps provide an example as to what a raised event is?

Comment: Have you tried just using something like `Private Sub trackChange() Handles eh.OnTrackChange`?

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set `eh.ListenForEvents = true`?
Without this set, events won't fire.

Regarding event-syntax, this should be correct:

```
AddHandler eh.OnTrackChange, AddressOf trackchange
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to do that! Yes, that was the solution!